# Auto increment textbox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How do I get to increment a textbox content after clicking on a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in the button click event

```
Dim int As Integer
Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, int)
TextBox1.Text = (int + 1)
```